# 3D math rotating around an arbitrary axis

Tags: opengl, math, 3d

I'm working with modern opengl and I need some help with rotating around an arbitrary axis. so basically when i rotate the 3D model I also need to rotate its collision box. glm handles all the rotation math for the model itself I just need to be able to rotate the collision box. I tried learning that, but i'm having trouble, can anyone help with this? https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm

```
if (model->collision_box->aX.x >= this->collision_box->ax.x && this->collision_box->aX.x > model->collision_box->ax.x){
    if (model->collision_box->aY.y >= this->collision_box->ay.y && this->collision_box->aY.y > model->collision_box->ay.y){
        if (model->collision_box->aZ.z >= this->collision_box->az.z && this->collision_box->aZ.z > model->collision_box->az.z){
            mx = 0;//stop movement
            my = 0;
            mz = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

bump: btw the 8 points of the collision box are stored as vec3 points so they can be rotated. It's not just min/max. Also if I used convex collision boxes I still need to rotate around an arbitrary axis!

Comment: If you are using an AABB as a collision box, then it doesn't rotate by definition, you need to use OBB or sacrifice some precision and use a bounding sphere

Comment: @concept3d why wouldnt the collision box be able to rotate. its defined by Ax ax aY ay aZ az. if i applied a rotation to it it would change the location of those points. For example if i rotated a rectangle model by 90 i would need to rotate the collision box 90 degrees aswell or they would not match up

Comment: can you show the code for your bounding box ?

Comment: @concept3d added, it checks that its between the maximum and minimum of each axis of the object

Comment: Your collision box is defined using max and min it's an Axially Aligned box. You can't rotate that. You either recalculate after every rotation or use sth else.

Comment: yes it does recalculate it when the model is rotated. i also scale and transform the collision box when the same is done to the model

Comment: given what you described you don't need to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

When you have an object who's bounding box is defined as the min and max of its vertices, what you have is an **A**xis **A**ligned **B**ounding Box. When this updates as the object moves or rotates like so:

[image: Dynamic AABB]

The box stays aligned to the primary axes. If you rotate the box along with the object, you have an **O**bject **A**ligned **B**ounding **B**ox and you don't need to update its dimension unless the objects vertices are modified (or it's scaled).

Here's an example of an AABB vs an OOBB.

[image: AABB vs OOBB]

An AABB is more efficient to intersect, but OOBBs are easier to maintain for dynamic objects. For first-order tests, you can also use spherical bounding volumes (which are rotation invariant).

*PS: Credit for the GIF, taken from the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZBTj7rwack)*

Comment: ah I see, but I still need to update the bounding box when it's rotated. How would I adjust the box to best fit the model as its rotated. Because for example if I rotate a rectangle the bounding box need to adjust to fit it. It was easy to adjust the bounding box when it was translated / scaled but not when its rotated

Comment: What are you trying to do with this box? Calculate collisions? Depending on how often this model rotates and how tight you want the bounding box to be, OOBBs might be cheaper (see http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9857/axis-aligned-bounding-box-once-rotated).

Comment: the gifs are really nice, thank you. I think the most efficient way will be to check if the collision spheres are colliding and if so check using OBB collisions for accuracy